# Python code can't find HTML element

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

While crawling this page (http://bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar_view.php?no=652455&gubun=I), my code returns error message which I can't understand.

Under the div tag (div class='rightarea'), there are a number of tags. But when I try to read and collect the data, it keeps returning error message, (content_table1 = table.find_all('div', class_='information') 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'). The weird thing is my code doesn't return any error message to collect this part of data in different list pages.

Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import quote
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import csv

URL = 'http://bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar_view.php?no=652455&gubun=I'
res = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
html = res.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Basic Information
table = soup.find_all('div', class_='rightarea')
print(table)

# Number, Year, Mileage, Gas Type, Color, Accident
content_table1 = table.find_all('div', class_='information')
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
table = soup.find_all('div', class_='rightarea') # will return a list like [div_tag, div_tag, ...]
```

`table.find_all('div', class_='information')` is euqal to:

```
[div_tag, div_tag, ...].find_all('div', class_='information')
```

Only the `tag` object can use `find_all()`, you should iterate over the `table list`, get the `div tag`, than use `find_all()`

```
for t in table:
    t.find_all('div', class_='information')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Basic Information
table = soup.find_all('div', class_='rightarea')
print(table)
```

soup.findall return a bs4.element.ResultSet. There are two items. The first one is "'div', class_='information'".

```
(Pdb) type(table)
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
(Pdb) len(table)
2

(Pdb) table[0]
<div class="rightarea">\n<div class="information">...

(Pdb) table[1]
<div class="rightarea">\n<div class="spectitle">...

(Pdb) table[0].find_all('div', class_='information')
[<div class="information">\n<dl>\n<dt>\n<span><em>5,480</em>....
```

So, in your scripts, update this line should get it working.

```
content_table1 = table[0].find_all('div', class_='information')
```